# Should I use "no_feed_story"=1 or "no_feed_story"=true?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, feed

When posting OpenGraph object from iOs app, I notices one can make use of "no_feed_story".

From the documentation and from looking in the community and on the web, it is unclear whether we should use integers or boolean to set this parameter true or false.

Should one use the integers 0 and 1, or the "strings" true and false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Posting multiple actions for the same real-world action. If you need
>   to post multiple actions to generate the right timeline units, you
>   must turn off feed stories for those actions (no_feed_story=1).

From the Facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/overview/

I guess 0 and 1 are more appropriate.